# AWS - Access the volume and fix own of the folders

Tags: linux, amazon-web-services, chown

My server was perfect until I used some chown commands.

So after that I even could not connect via putty or FTP.

I received:

> Server refused our key.

So then I created a new instance and attached my volume to it.

I had mounted the volume but i cannot access anything because every folder is permission denied

What should I do? It is getting me crazy!

[image]

Comment: if you connect as root, are you able to change owner / permission of folder ?

Comment: `sudo ls ...` you are logged in as an unprivileged user.

Answer (score 0):

Change the user from 'ec2-user' to 'root' using `sudo su` and then you will be able to access all the directories.